# How to filter only the necessary data from list of lists?

Tags: python-3.x, nested-lists

I have a document which is list of lists. This list is my data.

```
[['From john.johnson@gmail.com Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2019'], ['Received: from 
nakamura.uits.iupui.edu (localhost [127.0.0.1])'], 'Received: from murder ([unix socket])'], 
['by mail.umich.edu (Cyrus v2.2.12) with LMTPA;'], ['From tom.tompson@gmail.com Sat Jan  5 
13:57:23 2019']['Fri, 04 Jan 2019 18:10:48 -0500'], ['Received: from i . 
cestorm.mr.itd.umich.edu (icestorm.mr.itd.umich.edu [141.211.93.149])'], ['From 
peter.peterson@gmail.com Sat Jan  5 18:27:37 2019']]
```

I want to catch only those containing emails in them, starting with 'From ' . The output I'm looking for is:

```
[['From john.johnson@gmail.com Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2019'], ['From tom.tompson@gmail.com Sat 
Jan  5 13:57:23 2019']['From peter.peterson@gmail.com Sat Jan  5 18:27:37 2019']]
```

I want to take each element in the list and check if it contains 'From '. If so, I want to append it to the emaillst. The code I have doesn't produce any outcome.

```
lst = list(data)
emaillst = list()
for k in lst:
    if 'From ' in k:
        emaillst = emaillst.append(k)
        print(emaillst)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `data` is a list of lists, you'll need a nested loop in order to access the innermost items. Then `'From ' in k` checks if that string exists anywhere in `k`, not just at the start; for that purpose you can use `k.startswith('From ')`. Also note that `list.append` returns `None` as it is an in-place modification of the list, i.e. assigning `emaillst = emaillst.append(k)` is not necessary. So to sum up, you could use the following list comprehension:

```
email_list = [[k for k in sublist if k.startswith('From ')] for sublist in data]
```

Comment: This only works for the elements that start with 'from', not for those that start with something like 'received.'

Comment: @Kris As the OP states, *"I want to catch only those containing emails in them, starting with `'From '`"*. So I think that is was has been asked for.

Comment: you're right. I completely missed that bit of the question from the OP.

Answer (score 2):

You almost got it. However when you do `if 'From ' in k:`, you are forgetting that k is a list and not a string!

Try this instead:

```
lst = list(data)
emaillst = []
for k in lst:
    if k[0].startswith('From '):
        emaillst.append(k)
```

Your `lst` is a list of lists (`data`), and your `data` is a list with a single element, so you need to get the first element `([0])`.

Output:

```
print(emaillst)
> [['From john.johnson@gmail.com Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2019'], ['From tom.tompson@gmail.com Sat 
Jan  5 13:57:23 2019']['From peter.peterson@gmail.com Sat Jan  5 18:27:37 2019']]
```

EDIT: your list of list is incorrect as well ([What is missing](https://prnt.sc/q2d19g)).

Use this one:

> [['From john.johnson@gmail.com Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2019'],
>   ['Received: from nakamura.uits.iupui.edu (localhost [127.0.0.1])'],
>   ['Received: from murder ([unix socket])'], ['by mail.umich.edu (Cyrus
>   v2.2.12) with LMTPA;'], ['From tom.tompson@gmail.com Sat Jan  5
>   13:57:23 2019'],['Fri, 04 Jan 2019 18:10:48 -0500'], ['Received: from
>   i . cestorm.mr.itd.umich.edu (icestorm.mr.itd.umich.edu
>   [141.211.93.149])'], ['From peter.peterson@gmail.com Sat Jan  5
>   18:27:37 2019']]

Comment: I actually tried it and got an error: list index out of range on line 4.

Comment: @LinaLinutina print the k if you can, do you have any empty list?

Comment: @DuarteCastanho Did you run this code? Since you include the `print` call you should've realized that `emailst` is `None` after the first iteration. Don't assign to the return value of `append`.

Comment: @a_guest whoops my mistake, yes i ran the code however i made my own and tried to use this one for the answer, fixed.